# Reasons to setup cronjob for setup:cron:run and update/cron.php on a deployed production system?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, cron, magento-2.1, deployment

In Magento 2 there are three commands that should be set up as cronjob

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

> The first command (`magento cron:run`) reindexes indexers, send automated e-mails, generates the sitemap, and so on. Usually it’s associated with the PHP command line `.ini` file. The other two commands are used by the Component Manager and System Upgrade.

<sup>**Source:** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html</sup>

If I understand the docs correctly, `update/cron.php` and `bin/magento setup:cron:run` are only used for module installations and updates from the admin panel.

This is something that does not happen in a properly deployed production system where all updates are at least done on a staging system first, then moved to production.

So is there any reason to set up these cronjobs? What changes if I leave them out?

Comment: Where is that `update/cron.php` ?

Comment: The `update` directory is not in the GitHub repository, also can't find it in `vendor`, composer installs it out of nowhere it seems.

Comment: Interesting, I made an install from GitHub and can't find it.

Comment: That's explained in the docs: "These cron jobs work in the Web Setup Wizard, which contributing developers cannot use for installing or updating the Magento application or components." (contributing developers = installed from GitHub)

Comment: Lol ended up asking a question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134449/magento-2-where-is-the-update-cron-php-file

Comment: Do the 2 last commands only check if new updates are available or do they actually try to automatically install the updates? This would sound like a safe way to break production.

Comment: @FabianSchmengler I assume in production we should only run `/bin/magento cron:run`. Any updates on this?

Comment: @FabianSchmengler did you get  idea on this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updater and Setup cron jobs are used during upgrade via Web Setup Wizard only. Particularly, to enable message exchange between Setup component and Updater application. So if you are not planning to use Web Setup Wizard, it should be safe to disable these cron jobs. The worst thing that might happen, you will get readiness check failure on the attempt of using Web Setup Wizard.

Updater is an application independent from the Magento itself. It is used during Magento upgrade via Web Setup Wizard only and is distributed as part of Magento **project** package (not as Magento module and is not included into Magento product metapackage). It lives in a separate private git repository.

Since the updater cannot upgrade itself, it is the only component in Magento, which can only be upgraded manually via CLI. It means that you will not get newer updater version automatically during upgrade of Magento.