# Magento 2: where is the update/cron.php file?

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-2.1

Following this interesting question from Fabian: [Reasons to setup cronjob for setup:cron:run and update/cron.php on a deployed production system?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134443/reasons-to-setup-cronjob-for-setupcronrun-and-update-cron-php-on-a-deployed-pr)

I've discovered that **my Magento 2 installed via GitHub does not have the `update/cron.php` file.**

Edit: **my install does not have an `update` folder at all.**

Where does that file come from ? How can I get it when installing from GitHub ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read the doc a second time (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html) and here's the answer:

> If you cloned the GitHub repository you don’t have an update directory
>   and errors result if you run magento setup:cron:run. These cron jobs
>   work in the Web Setup Wizard, which **contributing developers cannot use
>   for installing or updating the Magento application or components.**

So basically **people using Magento 2 from GitHub can't use the Web Setup Wizard to install/update Magento components,** which is painful if let's say you installed M2 via GitHub and wanna switch to Web Setup Wizard after some point.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You should not start projects based on GitHub. It does not work with updates properly. Think of it like a library to use. you would not develop within the library tree but just include the library as a dependency