# Magento 2: why contributers can't use the Web Setup Wizard?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.1, composer, web-setup-wizard

So earlier today I was [looking for my `update/cron.php` folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134449/magento-2-where-is-the-update-cron-php-file) and I ended up finding that:

> If you cloned the GitHub repository you don’t have an update directory
>   and errors result if you run magento setup:cron:run. These cron jobs
>   work **in the Web Setup Wizard, which contributing developers cannot use
>   for installing or updating the Magento application or components**.

So my questions are simple:

- is there a **technical reason why people installing M2 from GitHub can't use the Web Setup Wizard** ?
- why **didn't Magento team include the `update` folder in the GitHub repo** ?
- is there any way one can **switch to the Web Setup Wizard after installing via GitHub ?**

Regarding my last point, Peter O'Callaghan suggested:

> Maybe grab the `update` folder from the meta package but that might
>   now work without the composer dependencies of the core packages.

I don't see the point of limiting users of using one or another way of updating.

Comment: The github repo is constantly being updated whereas the stable version gets large intermittent updates. The repo is going to be 'ahead' of these updates so it doesn't make sense to apply them if your a contributor.

Comment: @AaronAllen yeah I'm aware of that but if someone pulls a branch (let's say 2.0.5) then the branch must reflect the stable version thus one should be able to switch to Web Setup Wizard whenever they want. Does that make sense ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web Setup Wizard is based on Composer, so it is able to update only composer packages.
If it is a git-based installation (as for contributing developers) what you can do:

1. You can install the Updater from repo.magento.com `omposer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/updater`
2. You can use Setup Wizard to install/update/uninstall new packages (not Magento core packages) of specific versions. So they will be downloaded from repo.magento.com.
3. You can use Setup Wizard to enable/disable modules.
4. You can NOT use Setup Wizard for upgrading the entire Magento (System 
   Upgrade). The technical reason is that your Magento is git-based and Setup Wizard does not support Git.