# Magento 2 Cron Setup

Tags: magento2, cron, cli

The documentation for Magento 2 (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html) states that there should be three cron entries:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Magento state that the jobs do the following:

> The first command (magento cron:run) reindexes indexers, send automated e-mails, generates the sitemap, and so on. Usually it’s associated with the PHP command line .ini file. The other two commands are used by the Component Manager and System Upgrade.

I get the `magento cron:run` entry but can somebody please elaborate what the other two cron jobs do in more detail? Are these needed for a production store?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/134443/2380

Comment: Apologies, I missed that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember right:

- `update/cron.php` is used to update the composer components automatically via Cron
- `bin/magento setup:cron:run` is used to update the Magento application automatically via Cron

Comment: Thank you. Seems odd they would suggest setting that up...