# Magento 2.3.7 upgrade cron error

Tags: magento2.3, cron, php-7.3, magento2.3.7

I've recently upgraded from Magento 2.3.6-p1 to 2.3.7. Front end and everything works great (and on PHP7.3), but the following cron fails:

```
/usr/bin/php7.x /path/to/magento/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /path/to/magento/bin/magento/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

I am aware this cron has been removed in 2.4+, but have found no reference to its removal in Magento 2.3.7, any insight from anyone to confirm? I've been searching the internet but found very little usage examples on 2.3.7!

Comment: I am aware this cron has been removed in 2.4+ ??? who said this? send me link plz. I dont heard this yet

Comment: @GohilRajesh refer to the setup docs for Magento 2.4 crons https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html
I have not found a "factual" explanation document on Magento docs explaining this difference between Magento 2.3.x and 2.4.x, and more particularly to this question, 2.3.7's part in it but it is a stepping stone route for gradual migration to Magento 2.4 one step at a time!

Answer (score 1):

Reference:
[Reasons to setup cronjob for setup:cron:run and update/cron.php on a deployed production system?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134443/reasons-to-setup-cronjob-for-setupcronrun-and-update-cron-php-on-a-deployed-pr)

I was asking the wrong question but it may help others!

This cron "setup:cron:run" is part of the redundant Web Setup Wizard and can safely be removed along with "update/cron.php".